# Cabal repl is very slow

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cabal

I've already setup the IOHK binary cache in `/etc/nix/nix.conf`, yet when I build PPP lecture #2 I have to build many modules.

[image]

whereas it seems Lars only has to process one.

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

That should happen only the first time, when you make the `cabal repl` because it's building all dependencies.

After that, every `cabal repl` should look like Lars screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well it works yet, but the latest GHC release does improve on compilation time and memory footprint.

https://discourse.haskell.org/t/ghc-9-2-1-released/3527